# Word list: 2 consonants 2 vowels

Tags: wordplay, no-computers

Original 4 letter word

- - - - Two consonants Two Vowels

All next words use the exact same 2 consonants and exact same 2 vowels. Order not important

Next word 5 letters

- - - - - Same 2 consonants same 2 vowels only

Next word 6 letters

- - - - - - Same 2 consonants same 2 vowels only

Next word 8 letters

- - - - - - - - Same 2 consonants same 2 vowels only

Next word 10 letters

- - - - - - - - - - Same 2 consonants and same 2 vowels only

So all words only have same 2 consonants and same 2 vowels, nothing else. Of course starting with 5 letter words some of those will appear more than once.

All words contain the original 4 letter word, unbroken.

What are these words? No proper nouns or names please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Head
> Ahead: in the lead
> Headed: having a head
> Deadhead: remove dead flowers head
> Deadheaded: a person who travels without paying his ticket

Comment: Dang it, I just figured this out and came to add it!Well done. +1

Answer (score 2):

> READ
>  DREAD
>  REREAD/READER
>  REREADER
>  DEREADERED/DEREREADER. The removal of readers and rereaders...(?)

Not super happy with some of those, but it felt plausible. Hopefully, someone else has a better answer...

Here's a near miss:

> PEAR, ??, APPEAR, APPEARER, REAPPEARER. Just the 5 letter doesn't work. And I'm not sure of the reappear. Would it normally be re-appear?

Here's a better attempt:

> CARE
>  CARER
>  CAREER
>  CAREERER - one who careers (ie crashes around)
>  RECAREERER - one who careers again. Again it uses the re- suffix, but it might be necessary

Comment: The last one (10 letter) questionable Dr. Xorile

Comment: I agree completely...

Comment: I've added a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well it could be(a partial answer)

> POSE
>  POSES
>  OPPOSE
>  OPPOSES 
>  Eight letter word to be provided.
>  POSSESSEES

Comment: The last word does not contain the first word unbroken. (Second-last line of the question)

Comment: Correct Apep. And the last word is also not spelled correctly. It should be POSSESSES a 9 letter word

Comment: Possessee is one who is possessed. At least plausibly... But doesn't have pose in it

Answer (score -3):

Here's my best shot:

> FADE
>   
>   FADED
>   
>   FADEIN
>   
>   FADEOUTS
>   
>   INTIFADEH

The last is an alternative spelling to INTIFADA

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.

Comment: @user42225 can't use any letters but only those in first 4 letter word.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Unfortunately, this doesn't constitute a valid answer to the question, which specifies that only the four letters appearing in the first word can be contained in the other words.